# Definition of hypersurface singularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am really confused about this notion.

Suppose $X$ is an arbitrary variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ (if you like, let the characteristic be $0$), and $p$ is a $k$-valued point. If $p$ is an isolated singularity, what is the definition that $p$ is a *hypersurface singularity*? I guess we do not need $X$ to be a hypersurface for this definition.

More generally, for an arbitrary variety, not necessarily projective, how do we define the hypersurface singularity on it?

Comment: Typically, a hypersurface singularity is defined as follows. Consider the completion of $\mathcal{O}_X,p$.  This should be isomorphic to a ring of the form $k[[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/f$ for some $f$ and if it is a singularity, order of $f$ should be at least 2.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any references on this?